# Can't find any document about org-babel-clean-text-properties function

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I found org-babel-clean-text-properties in someone's code which is written in 2009. But I can't find any document about it and it is not defined in org-mode 8.3beta.

Anyone knows where can i find document about it or any other function as replacement for it?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/69453), which contains as part of a change log:

```
  (obe-citations): replace non-existent org-babel-clean-text-properties
  with org-no-properties
```

So I guess `org-no-properties` is the replacement function.